# How to get selectize.js to work with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, selectize.js

I am trying to implement a tagging system UI like the one seen on meteor forums (with dropdown menu of tags, colored squares, and descriptions.)

[image: Meteor forums example]

After some googling, I have come to the conclusion that selectize.js (https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) is one of the richest and most actively managed libraries for accomplishing tagging.
My current install of selectize.js: (*note: I already tried installing jeremy:selectize meteor package but didn't work either*)

1. selectize.js is in client/lib
2. all stylesheets and other helper js files are in client/

However I can't get the following simple example to work https://www.github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/customization.html in a meteor project.

**When I click the select box, no dropdown of options appears, they are not even generated. :/** All I get is this:

[image: an in focus selectize field but no dropdown!]

----------HERE is my implementation in a meteor project----------

```
//js
Template.hello.onRendered(function(){
    $('#select-links').selectize({
      maxItems: null,
      valueField: 'id',
      searchField: 'title',
      options: [
        {id: 1, title: 'DIY', url: 'https://diy.org'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Google', url: 'http://google.com'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Yahoo', url: 'http://yahoo.com'},
      ],
      render: {
        option: function(data, escape) {
          return '<div class="option">' +
              '<span class="title">' + escape(data.title) + '</span>' +
              '<span class="url">' + escape(data.url) + '</span>' +
            '</div>';
        },
        item: function(data, escape) {
          return '<div class="item"><a href="' + escape(data.url) + '">' + escape(data.title) + '</a></div>';
        }
      },
      create: function(input) {
        return {
          id: 0,
          title: input,
          url: '#'
        };
      }
    });

});
<!-- html -->
<template name="hello">
<select id="select-links" placeholder="Pick some links..."></select>
</template>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! If you give me a good answer, I will mark it as so.

Thanks - your fellow meteorite - Alex

Comment: I copied this code verbatim into my project and it worked as expected.  Do you have jquery added to your project?  Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: Wow nice! Yes jquery is added to the project and is loaded before any of the other js files also I have no errors in console. Out of curiosity what does you directory structure look like ?

Comment: I'm using an "everything as a package" structure, but that is not necessary for this.  But in any event, i'm using the jeremy:selectize package, and the template and js were in a separate package, with the html loaded before the js.

Comment: awww crap figured it out. I had 4 different selectize calls (b/c I was testing four different select fields) After I removed the other 3, it is now working as expected. That is weird :/ but it works now. Seriously thanks for taking the time to respond appreciate it buddy!